# Race condition when using mutex and reflect

Tags: go, mutex

The Go race detector is reporting a race condition when using a mutex and reflect on the struct being locked, example code is below. Even though both the reflect and access to the struct member is protected by locking the mutex the race detector still reports a race condition.

How can I solve the contention?

Code:

```golang
// main file
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
)

type TestType struct {
    counter uint64
    lock sync.Mutex
}

func NewTestType() *TestType {
    t := &TestType{
        counter: 0,
        lock:    sync.Mutex{},
    }

    go func() {
        t.lock.Lock()
        defer t.lock.Unlock()
        t.counter++
    }()

    return t
}

func ItShouldNotRace() string {
    t := NewTestType()

    t.lock.Lock()
    defer t.lock.Unlock()

    val := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    iface := val.Interface()
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", iface)
}

// test file
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestItShouldNotRace(t *testing.T) {
    if ItShouldNotRace() == "impossible" {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Race detector output:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000120078 by goroutine 7:
  reflect.typedmemmove()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/mbarrier.go:177 +0x0
  reflect.packEface()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:120 +0x12f
  reflect.valueInterface()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:1045 +0x1cd
  reflect.Value.Interface()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:1015 +0x3aa4
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:726 +0x3aa5
  fmt.(*pp).printValue()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:880 +0x25fc
  fmt.(*pp).printArg()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:716 +0x26b
  fmt.(*pp).doPrintf()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:1030 +0x326
  fmt.Sprintf()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:219 +0x73
  go_issue.ItShouldNotRace()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main.go:37 +0x1a4
  go_issue.TestItShouldNotRace()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main_test.go:8 +0x2f
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0x202

Previous write at 0x00c000120078 by goroutine 8:
  sync/atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/race_amd64.s:293 +0xb
  sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/sync/mutex.go:129 +0x14b
  sync.(*Mutex).Lock()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/sync/mutex.go:81 +0x84
  go_issue.NewTestType.func1()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main.go:21 +0x47

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  testing.(*T).Run()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1178 +0x796
  testing.runTests.func1()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1449 +0xa6
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0x202
  testing.runTests()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1447 +0x5aa
  testing.(*M).Run()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1357 +0x4eb
  main.main()
      _testmain.go:43 +0x236

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  go_issue.NewTestType()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main.go:20 +0x7a
  go_issue.ItShouldNotRace()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main.go:30 +0x54
  go_issue.TestItShouldNotRace()
      /Users/dedalus/Downloads/go_issue/main_test.go:8 +0x2f
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0x202
==================
--- FAIL: TestItShouldNotRace (0.00s)
    testing.go:1042: race detected during execution of test
```

Comment: By the way, you need not to explicitly initialize the `sync.Mutex` field with the zero value of its type: that'd be done automatically, it's not C. Of course, you will need to explicitly allocate a `sync.Mutex` on the heap should you follow the advice of @yury-fedorov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data race can be solved by making `lock` a pointer:

```golang
type TestType struct {
    counter uint64
    lock *sync.Mutex
}
```

From `sync.Mutex` docs:

```
// A Mutex must not be copied after first use.
```

Using a value type for `lock` field leads to copying this mutex.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. I simply didn't make the connection between `reflect.ValueOf(t)` and copying.

Comment: @Jacopo: As shown below, `reflect.ValueOf(t)` does _not_ copy the mutex. This is a possible solution, (not necessarily optimal), but you should definitely understand what you are actually copying here.

Comment: @JimB No the problem in this case was definitely the reflect. I only added the print statement in the example code. The original code that triggered this post had no print statement. Furthermore the trace from the race detector show the race inside the reflect stack trace.

Comment: @Jacopo, the reflects in the stack trace are called by the fmt package. Of course you could also read the mutex field with reflect, but that is definitely not done by `reflect.ValueOf` or `val.Interface` in this example

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the reflect value at all, you can replicate the race with a simpler example:

```
type TestType struct {
    sync.Mutex
}

func main() {
    t := &TestType{}

    go func() {
        t.Lock()
        defer t.Unlock()
    }()

    t.Lock()
    defer t.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", t)
}
```

The issue is that the `fmt.Printf` call is going to walk through the values provided in order to format the output, and in that process it must read the `sync.Mutex` value itself. This means that the race is in the reading of mutex value (a mutex should not be "read", as it's not a value that can be copied. The fact that `fmt` *does* read and print a private mutex value at all is debatably a bug, but not something that can be really be changed at this point)

If this is a value that you intend to pass to `fmt` frequently for output, then I would suggest adding `String`, `GoString` and/or `Format` methods to create a string value without reading the mutex itself.

Simply adding `fmt.Stringer` to the example above avoids the race condition.

```
func (t *TestType) String() string {
    return "TestType{}"
}
```

This is also convenient if you need to lock the value in order to read other fields as well. If we add back in your `counter` field, we need to serialize that access (note you need to remove the external lock call to prevent a deadlock here):

```
func (t *TestType) String() string {
    t.Lock()
    defer t.Unlock()
    return fmt.Sprintf("TestType{counter:%d}", t.counter)
}
```

The other way to avoid this is to use a pointer for a mutex, however that prevents you from using the zero value which tends to be preferred, and you still need to ensure that you externally lock the value so the other fields can be safely read. Since you already have a constructor, that may not be an issue, but it is something to consider

```
type TestType struct {
    *sync.Mutex
}

func NewTestType() *TestType {
    return &TestType{
        &sync.Mutex{},
    }
}
```